# Casting Func<T> to Func<object>

Tags: c#, silverlight, generics, delegates

I'm trying to figure out how to pass `Func<T>` to `Func<object>` method argument:

```
public void Foo<T>(Func<T> p) where T: class
{
    Foo(p);
}

public void Foo(Func<object> p)
{

}
```

**Strange thing, it works in NET 4.0 Class library, but doesn't work in Silverlight 4 Class library.**
Actually I want it to work in Silverlight, and I have input parameters like `Func<T, bool>`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
public void Foo<T>(Func<T> p) where T : class
{
    Func<object> f = () => p();
    Foo(f);
}
```

Comment: What about situation when i have input paramaters like Func<T,bool> ?

Comment: It's a bit different for a `Func<T, bool>`, since the T there is an input argument and we need to do a down cast, like this: `Func<object, bool> f = value => p((T)value);`. Note that this might not work correctly, since it is probably the `Foo` method that supplies the input argument and it might fail, since it might supply an `object` that can't be cast to our `T`.

Answer (score 12):

In C# 4.0 targeting .NET 4.0 (i.e. with *variance*) that is fine "as is", since there is a reference-preserving conversion from `T : class` to `object`. This is possible because `Func<T>` is *actually* defined as `Func<out T>`, making it covariant.

In previous versions of C#, or with C# 4.0 targeting earlier versions of .NET, you need to translate as per [Steven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624751/pass-funct-to-funcobject/6624770#6624770).

note, you will need disambiguation to prevent it being recursive! At the simplest, two method names. Or alternatively, `Foo((Func<object>)p)`.

Comment: for some strange reason it works in .NET4 but doesn't in Silverlight4

Comment: @Alex really? I am amazed. Honestly.

Comment: In Silverlight 4, Func is defined as: `public delegate TResult Func<TResult>()`, so it is not covariant